# Time or thread function in r5rs

Tags: time, scheme, racket, sleep, r5rs

I made a game which uses the time for calculating the effect of gravity in relation of the time (speed and movement). Although the game uses mostly r5rs functions, I used the `thread`, `sleep` and other functions to update and remember the time, which are defined in racket.
Now I want to make te game work on a microcontroller which has only r5rs available.
Is it possible to make something similar using only r5rs?

This is the code I currently use (which uses the racket functions):

```
(define (make-timer)
  (define time 0) 
  (define wait-time (/ 1 CPU_FREQ))  
  (define timer-thread
    (thread (lambda ()
              (let loop ()
                (sleep wait-time)
                (set! time (+ 1 time))
                (loop)))))

  (define (dispatch msg)
    (cond ((eq? msg 'time) time)
          ((eq? msg 'start)
           (thread-resume timer-thread))
          ((eq? msg 'restart)
           (set! time 0)
           (thread-resume timer-thread))
          ((eq? msg 'reset)
           (thread-suspend timer-thread)
           (set! time 0))
          ((eq? msg 'stop) (thread-suspend timer-thread))
          ((eq? msg 'set-period!)
           (lambda (period)
             (set! wait-time (* (+ period 1) (/ 1 CPU_FREQ)))))
          ))
  (thread-suspend timer-thread)
  (set! time 0)
  dispatch)
```

Comment: There are no concept of threads in R5RS. But do you have a particular microprocessor / Scheme implementation in mind?

Comment: Although not R5RS, ypsilon is an R6RS Scheme that has been used for game development and has multiprocessing primitives built in.

Answer (score 0):

No, in R5RS there are no threading primitives (check the [index](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-15.html#%_chap_Temp_11) of the specification to see the available procedures). And it can't be implemented in terms of just R5RS, because necessarily at some point you'll have to access native operating system calls.